# Print full node url escaping special characters?

Tags: theming

How can I print the full node url in a tpl file escaping special characters?

So im using this:

```
<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>
```

Which gives me a url like http://time.com/3525666/ebola-psychology-fear-symptoms/

However I need the url to be like http%3A%2F%2Ftime.com%2F3525666%2Febola-psychology-fear-symptoms%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to generate a URL is with the [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) function, and the `absolute` option:

```
$absolute_url = url('node/123', array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

You then need to [encode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode) it:

```
$encoded_url = rawurlencode($absolute_url);
```

This work should be done in a preprocess function, and the variable added to `$variables`, and not done in the .tpl.php file directly:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $absolute_url = url('node/123', array('absolute' => TRUE));
  $encoded_url = rawurlencode($absolute_url);

  $variables['encoded_url'] = $encoded_url;
}
```

and then printed in the template.

```
<?php print $encoded_url ?>
```

However, you more than likely want to use the `query` option or [`drupal_http_build_query`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7)  for whatever you are trying to use this for.  What you are describing typically isn't needed directly.  Giving the proper advice, though, is a little hard without more context.

Comment: I need to use this in a content type tpl file, so every node page will have its own url. Your code looks like node 123 will always be used?

Comment: @jdln just substitute 123 with nid you want. I'm sure you can do it.